# Could a BeginInvokeOnMainThread method be looping and causing a memory leak?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that works but after a while when I debug on my iPhone it hangs the phone and the only way I can recover is a hard reset of the button on the side and the home button.

First of all, could that be because my application has a memory leak?

Here's the code for the application.  In particular, I am looking at the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method. Can someone tell me if they can see if there could be any problems with the way that it is implemented? Also, what's the purpose of the `.ContinueWith((arg)`.

```cs
namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
    {

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public PhrasesFrame(PhrasesPage phrasesPage)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.phrasesPage = phrasesPage;
            AS.phrasesFrame = this;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ShowCards(cts.Token).ContinueWith((arg) => { }));
        }

        public void Disappearing()
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }

        public async Task ShowCards(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            AS.cardCountForSelectedCategories = App.DB.GetCardCountForSelectedCategories();
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop freeze the UI as the Main Thread is the UI Thread.  ContinueWith is executed when your ShowCards Task has ended.

Comment: Where do you invoke the Disappearing? Since !ct.IsCancellationRequested is always true, it will freeze the Main Thread.

Comment: My first guess would be that you should call BeginInvokeOnMainThread in the constructor. iOS is very sensible on doing some things in the constructor. You should override OnAppearing

Other than that it does sound completely wrong that you have a while loop whose only purpose is to awake ContinueWith that has no code.

Could you try those?

Comment: I don't see why you call Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread because nothing on UI is updated. "While" loop is useless as it doesn't do anything besides waiting. To remove ContinueWith as it does nothing you can add async like this: async () => await ShowCards(cts.Token). What theoretically can cause memory leak is 2 lines: this.phrasesPage = phrasesPage;  AS.phrasesFrame = this; You store reference to the page inside your frame and reference of your frame in AS object which is not clear what is that. As @DavidOliver said you can check leak overriding ReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: For your requirements don't use Stopwatch. It might be high resolution timer (based on the system) and as such probably consumes more CPU than you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## ContinueWith

First, let's address your question about `.ContinueWith((arg) => { }))`. `ContinueWith` tells more code to execute once the original `Task` has completed. In our case, the code inside of `ContinueWith` will run once `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ShowCards(cts.Token)` has finished.

In this case, there is no code inside of `ContinueWith`, so we can remove it.

## Freezing

Yes, I can see that this code has potential to freeze the UI.

`BeginInvokeOnMainThread` will queue an `Action` to run on the Main Thread (also known as the UI Thread). The Main Thread is constantly listening for user input (tapping a button on the screen, pinch-to-zoom, etc.), and if this thread is busy doing a long-running task, it will not be able to respond to a user's input until it has finished; thus your app will appear frozen.

The code `await Task.Delay(500);` is being called by the Main Thread. We are thus telling the Main Thread to freeze itself for 500 milliseconds, and looping that indefinitely.

One solution would be to wrap this code in `Task.Run` which would put it in a background-thread and free the Main Thread to listen/respond to user input.

```cs
Task.Run(async () => 
{ 
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
          await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

## More Threading Recommendations

- Only use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` when you need to update the UI. 99% of code can run on a background thread with no problems. The 1%, however, is code that updates the UI; any code that updates the UI *must* be run on the Main Thread.
- If a task that takes longer than the refresh rate of the screen to execute, perform it on a background thread. For example, if the screen's refresh rate is 60Hz, it is updating 60-times per second, every 16.7ms. So if we have a block of code that takes 20ms to execute, we need to execute it on a background thread to ensure that we don't freeze the app and drop any frames.

  - The code above looks like it is accessing a database, which I would highly recommend moving to a background thread like so

```cs
await Task.Run(() => AS.cardCountForSelectedCategories = App.DB.GetCardCountForSelectedCategories());
```

Comment: I think explanation like yours deserve 10 rather than 1 points.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are concerned about a memory leak, you can check for low-memory warnings in the device logs (accessible through XCode), or override the [ReceiveMemoryWarning](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.ReceiveMemoryWarning/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication/) method in your app delegate to log an error.

Secondly, there's nothing obviously wrong with the way you're calling BeginInvokeOnMainThread that would cause a leak. The ContinueWith is a no-op that doesn't affect the operation of the code - I'm guessing it's there to avoid a compiler warning that you're not awaiting the task.

Thirdly, if you suspect that this code is causing a leak, you should use logging and/or breakpoints to confirm that it's behaving as expected. Is the task correctly cancelled when you navigate away from the page? Do you see multiple instances of of the ShowCards task running? If this code turns out to be behaving correctly, then the source of the hang lies elsewhere in your app. <s>For instance, it looks like you're making a database call twice a second - maybe it's not cleaning up resources properly.</s>

Comment: where do you see database calls twice per second?

Comment: I don't see them as such, it's a guess as to what the App.DB.GetCardCountForSelectedCategories() call might be doing.

Comment: Yes, but did you notice that it is outside the loop?